# unable to start Hyperledger explorer

Tags: hyperledger-explorer

When I try to start the Explorer by the command (./start.sh) this message appear (***** Please check the log [logs/console/console-2019-08-09.log] for any error *****)

Log file contents:

```
module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'helmet'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/shikah/fabric/blockchain-explorer/main.js:11:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

In the main.js file, I tried to replace "require" with "import" but it does not resolve the problem.

Main.js file contents:

```
//Part of the main.js file:

const express = require('express');   
const helmet = require('helmet');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const url = require('url');
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const appconfig = require('./appconfig.json');
const helper = require('./app/common/helper');
```

Comment: try npm install inside the root folder

Comment: Thanks very much, this resolve the error but I got another error, I can't solve it. (false 'ssl-certs' '/home/shikah/fabric/blockchain-explorer/ssl-certs'
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Explorer Error >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
{ Error: Cannot find module 'fabric-network' ....)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the latest tutorials from here: https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer

```
./main.sh install
--to install, run tests, and build project

./main.sh clean
--to clean the /node_modules, client/node_modules client/build, client/coverage, app/test/node_modules directories

./main.sh test
--to test REST API, and UI components
--to generate code coverage report
```

In your case, first run **./main.sh clean** then **./main.sh install**

Hope it will be solved